# Angular link is showing a text as being highlighted even after a modal pop up closed

Tags: angular

I have the following code that opens the modal pop up and also while hover over it highlights.

```
<a class="mylink" href="#" ng-bind-html="presentation.displayStates" ng-click="ctrl.displayStates(country)">States</a>
```

Basically, I get all the states, and clicking on it, it opens to modal. But when I close the modal either by clicking on its X cross button and or clicking outside the modal, it returns to the parent page (All good). But it doesn't remove the highlight of the link. :( How to remove the highlighted display when I return back? I can however, manually do this by clicking in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have css where its written, that when user has visited link that time you need to make link to some color.

so remove that css or add custom css.

```
a:visited { // After clicking on link you can remove highlight by this css.
    color: green; 
}
```

Comment: You are right, I observed that behavior. Thank you so much, but looks like its no more a defect